# boost::thread vs std::thread vs pthread

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, pthreads, boost-thread

What are the tradeoffs b/w `boost::thread`, `std::thread` (C++11), and `pthread` for high CPU throughput (read: lots of floating point operations) Linux based applications? When should one implementation be used over the others?

The use case here is to call a routine on a buffer (or pointer to a buffer) of contiguous memory, do some work, and return -- in a multithreaded implementation.

Comment: I would say, there should be no visible difference among those three (if i'm right, std::thread comes from boost::thread). The first two also rely on pthread on platforms which support pthread. The only case where pthread could have an advantage would be if using some pthread-specific features not supported by std/boost::thread.

Comment: Unless you continuously create lots of threads and use synchronization primitives a lot, there's no performance difference. Floating-Point performance is not affected by the threading API. `std::thread` has the advantage of being in the standard library and being portable, `boost::thread` has some extra features, and `pthread` is only available on POSIX.

Comment: for `lots of floating point operations` it would be better to use alternatives like `omp`, `eigen`, `OpenCV`, `OpenCL` ... depending on application. For example using `OpenCL` you can move parallel operation to video card which currently have lots of floating point power (lots of more then CPU).

Comment: Too many people think of threads in 'adversarial' terms, like separate processes, instead of cooperative terms. Concepts like cancellation are a mistake, that `std::thread` avoided. Detached threads are another mistake. Both of these make deterministic execution and resource unwinding (RAII) very difficult. I can't think of a good reason not to use C++ standard thread facilities if available.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

- `std::thread`

  - Pro: Is standard; guaranteed to be on all conforming platforms.
  - Con: Requires C++11, so it cannot be used with ancient compilers. Only basic, lowest common denominator features. However, platform specific features can still be used through `std::thread::native_handle`.
- `boost::thread`

  - Pro: Is cross platform, is supported on ancient compilers.
  - Con: Is not standard; requires an external dependency. Similar feature set as standard threads.
- `pthread`:

  - Pro: Has more features such as schduling policy.
  - Con: Is only on POSIX systems, which excludes Windows. Non-RAII interface.

> When should one implementation be used over the others?

`std::thread` is often a good default. If you need features of `pthread` that are not in the standard, you can use them with the help of `std::thread::native_handle` (with the implications on the portability that come with it). There's no reason to use `pthread` directly otherwise (that I know of) in C++.

`boost::thread` can be used if you need ancient pre-C++11 support, to remain portable to other systems.

---

Note that `std::thread` itself doesn't need to be used directly. The standard has useful abstractions such as `std::reduce`, `std::packaged_task`, `std::async`, parallel execution policies for algorithms etc.

Comment: Additional con of pthreads is that, AFAIK, it has no native C++ API.

Comment: Note that the portability issues with `std::thread::native_handle` go deeper than just the OS. According to the C++ standard, that name isn't required to exist; if it does exist, its meaning is entirely implementation defined.

Comment: `pthread_self` could be used instead, but that works only within the thread. Implementation defined is good though. If the implementation defines it to return what you need, then you're good to go. If it doesn't, then it probably doesn't use pthreads in the first place.

Comment: In fairness, pretty much any implementation on POSIX will use pthreads underneath, and `std::thread::native_handle` will, in fact, be the pthreads handle, with all the operations that can be done on that.

Answer (score 5):

The only standard-supported one is `std::thread` and you should use that if your build tools allow C++11 or higher. It's a derived but standardized version of `boost::thread`.

Pthreads are a platform-specific implementation of threading, `std::thread` is guaranteed by the standard as per C++11. Usually on POSIX like systems `std::thread` uses pthreads internally.